# HBase support for wildcards in RowKey

Tags: hbase

I was wondering if HBase supports wildcards on RowKey scans. Something similar to:

```
select * from TABLE where KEY like '%SEARCH_KEY%';
```

I understand we can use a partial key scan if we have some knowledge of the prefix to the rowkey (and HBase is very efficient with that scan). However, if we don't have the information prefixed (meaning the search key could be anywhere in the RowKey), then Hbase has to run a full table scan, correct?

Also, how can I form such a query in HBase (Either code or through the shell)?

Answer (score 4):

You can only do a prefix-based row-key scan.

Say you have data like:

```
aaa_001
aaa_002
aab_001
aac_001
baa_001
...
zzz_001
```

Using [HappyBase](http://happybase.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html), you can write code like this to get aaa*

```
for key in table.scan(row_prefix="aaa"):
  print key
```

will print

```
aaa_001
aaa_002
```

whereas this code:

```
for key in table.scan(row_prefix="aa"):
  print key
```

will get you this:

```
aaa_001
aaa_002
aab_001
aac_001
```

So you can do prefix-based matching, but not suffix-based. Hope this is useful.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Suman, however my questions was regarding if we don't have the prefix information and our search key could be in any portion of the rowkey. I think HBase isn't performant in that scenario and will require a full table scan. I just wanted to confirm this. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you could use column filters, but I do believe that requires a full table scan.

Answer (score 1):

You can use RegexStringComparator along with RowFilter and specify the regex, however it will endup in a full table scan.

```
RegexStringComparator comp = new RegexStringComparator("my.");   // any value that starts with 'my'
SingleColumnValueFilter filter = new SingleColumnValueFilter(
cf,
column,
CompareOp.EQUAL,
comp
);
scan.setFilter(filter);
```

Instead of SingleColumnValueFilter use a RowFilter